# Change bar chart color in plotly.express when source is a Series

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a simple series and want to change the color for every index.
This seems to be not possible. The first color (here: green), is accepted, to following not.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.Series([100,200,300,400],index=['Cat1','Cat2','Cat3','Cat4'])

colors=['green','yellow','red','blue']

fig= px.bar(x=df.index, y=df,color_discrete_sequence=colors)
fig.show()
```

Any ideas, that px acceptes the colors like described in the color-list?

Comment: Try this: `fig= px.bar(x=df.index, y=df, color=colors,)`

Comment: @r-beginners Hi, ok, this works, but only if the amount of colors has exactly the same length as the indexes. In my code, the series and the corresponding indexes could also be greater or smaller dynamically.
For a pie instead, this works fine with this code:
fig1= px.pie(names=df.index,values=df, color_discrete_sequence=colors). Here it takes 2 colors in case of the Series has 2 entries - and it takes all 4 colors in case of the series as 4 entries. With more, it interpolates anything. But the tag color_discrete_sequence does not work with px.bar

Comment: If what you are asking for is to add a specified color to the y-axis with a normalized value, the following code will do the job. `fig= px.bar(x=df.index, y=df, color=df, color_continuous_scale=[(0, "green"), (0.3333, "yellow"), (0.6666, 'red'), (1, "blue")])`

Comment: @r-beginners That´s not what I mean.
Please try this: ```fig=px.pie(names=df.index, values=df, color_discrete_sequence=colors).``` You will see, that 100 appears with green, 200 with yellow ... and so on. If I add a value to the series, e.g. 500, but have still only 4 colors, that is no problem and another green-tone is automatically chosen.
And I want the same for px.bar. But px.bar does not work with color_discrete_sequence and Series - don´t understand why.

Comment: @r-beginners ... solved it with your help: ```..... color=df.index, color_discrete_sequence=colors .... ```